# Is This a “Large” GraphViz Chart, and How to Fix it?

Tags: optimization, graphviz

I started using GraphViz yesterday in order to visualize the relationships between some things—a project I’ve been wanting to tackle for quite a while now.

So far, I’ve gotten it pretty well done, but there’s a few things I’m struggling with, specifically getting the chart to look good and how long it takes to process the DOT file—thank goodness I decided to use a computer ot do it instead of doing it by hand on paper!

It seems to me that the reason my graph looks so cluttered and why it takes so long is because there are so many entities and so many relationships in it (including many cyclical ones).

I’ve read of “large” graphs several times in the documentation and other resources on the Internet, but nothing that specifically indicates *what* is considered large, so I’m wondering if mine counts as large.

Simply put, I’ve got two groups of nodes (A and B), with relationships between items in A to items in B. Currently there are:

123 entries in group A
  55 entries in group B
  278 relationships
  ? cyclical relationships

Plus, I’m also considering adding relationships between items in group A.

So does this count as “large”? I was under the impression that “large” was thousands of items/links. (Depending on some minor changes, the resulting image is about 8444x7463 pixels. I’ve included a—relatively huge—thumbnail.)

If it is large, are there any tips on making a messy, convoluted graph look good?
If it is not large, then why am I having trouble with it (I am currently using non-overlapped and neato)?

Thanks a lot.
[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5493/mygraph.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/5493/mygraph.png)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give [Gephi](http://gephi.org/) a try, as I have found it easier to use than Graphviz.

Comment: Actually I already have a copy of Gephi (along with 48 other graphing applications). I’m using GraphViz (for now) because, so far, I have found it to be the easiest to work with (entering items and relationships is trivial and can be done in a plain-text file). If Gephi is even easier than that and is more powerful, then I’ll definitely try it.